# Не работает callback функция success в ajaxSubmit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit, jquery-validation

При отправке формы загорается прелоадер и так и остается и не выводится сообщение об успешной загрузке. При этом в форме предусмотрена отправка изображения, но я не валидирую их наличие, и ошибка возникает если изображение не загружено,а при наличии загруженного изображения все пучком. При отключении js браузер возвращает true.
 Вот код на js

```
    $('.form_post').validate({
                        //правила для проверки
                rules:{
                    user_name_input: {
                        required:true,
                    },
                    user_phone_input:{
                        required:true,
                    },
                    post_name: {
                        required:true,
                        maxlength:40,
                        minlength:2,
                    },
                    describe:{
                        required:true,
                    },
                },
                //сообщения о нарушении правила
                messages:{
                    user_name_input: {
                        required:'Введите имя',
                    },
                    user_phone_input:{
                        required:'Введите номер телефона',
                    },
                    post_name: {
                        required:"Укажите название!",
                        maxlength:"Максимум 40 символов",
                        minlength:"Минимум 2 символа",
                    },
                    describe:{
                        required:"Введите описание!",
                    },
                },
     submitHandler: function(form){
                    $("#form_block").fadeOut(300,function() {
                        $("#message").addClass("message_load").fadeIn(400).html("Подождите, загружается...");
                        $('#preloader_block').css('display','block');
                        $("#submit_post").hide();
                                });
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        success: function(result) {

                            if (result=='true') {
                                    $("#message").removeClass("message_load").addClass("message_good").html("Успешно добавлено");
                                    $("#preloader_block").remove();

                            }
                            else {
                                $("#message").removeClass("message_load").addClass("message_error").html(result);
                                $("#preloader_block").remove();


                            }
                            $('.form_post')[0].reset();
                        }
                    });
            }
    });
```

Вот код обработчика

```
    $result='true';
    return $result;
```

Ошибка в консоли браузера
        jquery.min.js:4 POST http:----/post/publish 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
fileUploadXhr @ jquery.form.js:346
$.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.js:254
submitHandler @ adv_insert.js:201
d @ jquery.validate.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.min.js:4
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Если при формы с изображением все хорошо, то сервер значит ждет от вас такие данные в которых содержится изображения. Если серверная часть на php, то это переменная `$_FILES`, а если такова пустая, возникает ошибка, отсюда и 500 ошибка.

Comment: Смотрите мой код сервера return true без всяких files